# How to maintain vertical scroll position when prepending to a list (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, cross-browser

I'm building a cross-browser chat widget in React with Redux. The events in the chat widget are paginated, and fetching older events is triggered by scrolling to the top of the list of events. The events are prepended to the list of events. The container's scroll position is held at the top on re-render, which triggers more refetching.  Rinse and repeat.

I tried storing the scroll position to state before fetching and diffing the new height with the old height after the fetch is successful, without success.

```
fetchOldMessages = () => {
//getMoreMessages updates the redux store, where messages are connected from.
    const { getMoreMessages, messages } = this.props
    const { isFetching, fetchedEventIds } = this.state
    const oldestMessage = messages[0]

    if (!oldestMessage || isFetching || fetchedEventIds.includes(oldestMessage.id) || !this.scrollContainerIsReady())
      return

    const currentPosition = this.ContainerRef.current.scrollHeight

    this.setState({ isFetching: true}, () => {

        getMoreMessages(oldestMessage).then(() => {
            const newPosition = this.ContainerRef.current.scrollHeight - currentPosition
            this.scrollContainerRefTo({left: 0, top: currentLocation})
          })

        this.setState({ 
            isFetching: false,
            fetchedEventIds: [...this.state.fetchedEventIds, oldestMessage.id],
        })

    })
 })
```

```
scrollContainerRefTo = opts => {
    if (!this.scrollContainerIsReady()) return null

    if (this.ContainerRef.current.scrollTo) {
      return this.ContainerRef.current.scrollTo(opts)
    }

    this.ContainerRef.current.scrollLeft = opts.left
    this.ContainerRef.current.scrollTop = opts.top
  }
```

```
render() {
const { messages } = this.props
    return (
      <div ref={this.ContainerRef}>

        {messages.reduce((acc, message, index) => {
           acc.push(
<Event key={message.id} message={message} onVisibile={index === 0 ? fetchOldMessages: null} />
)
           return acc
         },[])}

      </div>
    )
  }
```

I expect the container to, from the user's perspective, not scroll when messages are prepended. It should remain where it was at.

Thank you!